# How to zoom/pan in OxyPlot.PlotView inside NestedScrollView without scrolling?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-nestedscrollview, oxyplot

In my Android app made with `Xamarin.Android` I have a chart that uses `OxyPlot.Android`. The chart is a `PlotView` and is inside a `NestedScrollView`. The chart has pan and zoom enabled, but when I try to pan or zoom, the `NestedScrollView` also scrolls.

How do I prevent the `NestedScrollView` from scrolling while I touch the `PlotView`?

Comment: you'd need to 'handle' the scroll event in the nested scroll view.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt So I'd need to make a custom `NestedScrollView` that doesn't scroll when the view that was touched is a `PlotView`? Could you help me with where to start? What methods I need to override or how I figure out what view was touched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these event handlers to the plotview's model

```
plotView.Model.TouchStarted += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (plotView.Parent != null)
        plotView.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
};

plotView.Model.TouchCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (plotView.Parent != null)
        plotView.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
};
```